# Javascript regex to always find a match from the end?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which looks like below

```
str = "hey there = pola"
```

Now I need to check if there is equal `=` sign and the first word to the left of it. So this is what I do

```
str.match(/\w+(?= *=)/)[0]
```

So I get the desired result

But say I have a string like this

```
str = "hey there= pola so = boba"
```

Now I have two `=` signs. But the above regex will only give me the result for the first `=` sign.

Is there any regex that can always look for the first instance of `=` from the end of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert what is on the right is an equals sign followed by matching any char except an equals sign until the end of the string

```
\w+(?= *=[^=]*$)
```

In parts:

- `\w+`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `*=` Match 0+ occurrences of a space followed by `=`
- `[^=]*` Match 0+ occurrences of `=` ( Use `[^=\r\n]*` to not cross line breaks)
- `$` End of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s4fYJ0/1)

```js
const regex = /\w+(?= *=[^=]*$)/;
const str = `hey there= pola so = boba`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[0]);
```

Without using a lookahead, you could use a capturing group:

```
^.*\b(\w+) *=[^=]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XyGZMK/1)

```js
const regex = /^.*\b(\w+) *=[^=]*$/m;
const str = `hey there= pola so = boba`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```

Comment: I know this is stupid but I tried using your capturing group expression in my code like this `str.match(^.*\b(\w+) *=[^=]*$)[0]`. But I get token error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `const regex = /^.*\b(\w+) *=[^=]*$/m;
    const str = `hey there= pola so = boba`;
    console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);` I have added an example to the answer

Comment: Ok works now but had to use index [1] to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much expert on regex but for you requirement I think split and pop should work

```
let str = "hey there= pola so = boba";
let endres = str.split('=').pop(); // gives the last element in the split array
```

Hope this helps.